# Multiple Row value from joined Table in select column list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, pivot

I have two tables, `Order` and `Order_Tag`.

There are one or more entries for each `Order` in the `Order_Tag` table.

`Order` table:

| OrderKey | OrderNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABCD |
| 2 | CDEF |
| 3 | GHIJ |

`Order_Tag` table:

| OrderKey | TagName | TagValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | IntemNumber | 00001 |
| 1 | ItemDescription | Desc1 |
| 1 | ItemWeight | 12.5 |
| 2 | IntemNumber | 00002 |
| 2 | ItemDescription | Desc2 |
| 2 | ItemWeight | 99 |
| 3 | IntemNumber | 00003 |
| 3 | ItemDescription | Desc3 |
| 3 | ItemWeight | 111 |

How can I achieve this output:

| OrderKey | OrderNumber | IntemNumber | ItemDescription | ItemWeight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABCD | 00001 | Desc1 | 12.5 |
| 2 | CDEF | 00002 | Desc2 | 99 |
| 3 | CDEF | 00003 | Desc3 | 111 |

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I tried to join the Order_Tag table three times. There is a easier way to do this with a PIVOT.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding PIVOT function in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428993/understanding-pivot-function-in-t-sql) You can also do it with [conditional aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48405660/how-to-apply-conditional-aggregate-function-in-a-pivot)

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation.  I would do so using `APPLY`:

```
select o.*, ot.*
from orders o cross apply
     (select max(case when ot.tagName = 'IntemNumber' then TagValue end) as IntemNumber,
             max(case when ot.tagName = 'ItemDescription' then TagValue end) as ItemDescription,
             max(case when ot.tagName = 'ItemWeight' then TagValue end) as ItemWeight
      from order_tag ot
      where ot.OrderKey = o.OrderKey
     ) ot;
```